# PHP: How to access file not within web directory?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I just set up a digitalocean-server with ubuntu and LAMP.
This is the directory where my php files are located:
**/var/www**.
I want to access a file in
**/root/scrapy/myfile.csv**

I tried to access it like that:

```
$handle = @fopen("/root/scrapy/myfile.csv", "r");
echo $handle;
```

Unfortunately, $handle is empty.
It works if myfile is in **/var/www**.
What should I do?

Comment: Set appropriate file permissions.

Comment: myfile.csv has 777 permission

Comment: Not only file permissions. There are other factors that could be at play, such as permissions on the directory and its parents, `open_basedir` or SELinux. Either way, `/root` is probably not the best place for files like that.